# MKMapViewのタッチジェスチャ実装について

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

iPhoneアプリ(Objective-C)のMKMapViewを使った実装で、Mapスクロール操作と同等のタッチジェスチャを実装したいのですが、下記のようにすると、
タッチ後の指を動かし始めた直後に少しMapがずれて意図しない方向へ瞬間移動してしまいます。
その後、ドラッグし続けた場合、Mapはタッチに追従してスクロールされます。

タッチ後の指を動かし始めた直後の動作を修正するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D co;
MKMapView *mv;

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
mv.scrollEnabled= false;
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentPos = [mv convertPoint: [touch locationInView:mv]
toCoordinateFromView:mv];
CLLocationCoordinate2D previousPos = [mv convertPoint: [touch previousLocationInView:mv]
toCoordinateFromView:mv];
float diffLong = currentPos.longitude - previousPos.longitude;
float diffLat = currentPos.latitude - previousPos.latitude;
co.longitude -= diffLong;
co.latitude -= diffLat;
[mv setCenterCoordinate:co
animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13170614953

Comment: コードを読み間違えたコメントを入れたので一旦削除しました。もうちょっと確認して何か分かれば再度コメントします。

Comment: @OOPer さん  ありがとうございます、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ・`MKMapView`はタッチ対応でスクロールできるようになっているのはご存知だと思いますが、なぜ、スクロールを自前で処理しようとしているのでしょうか? ・`touchesBegan:withEvent:`の処理を記載してくださっていませんが、`co`はどのように初期化していますか?

Comment: > ・MKMapViewはタッチ対応でスクロールできるようになっているのはご存知だと思いますが、なぜ、スクロールを自前で処理‌​しようとしているのでしょうか?  =>スクロールの慣性などを調整し、自前のタッチジェスチャを作成したいと考えております.   
> touchesBegan:withEvent:の処理を記載してくださっていませんが、coはどのように初期化していますか‌​? =>  coは`viewDidLoad`にて  
    `co = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.68664111, 139.6948839);  `
としています。

Comment: 1点目了解しました…が、地球は丸いので極付近まで表示の対象にしたいのなら実装はかなり難しいかもしれません。2点目については「`touchesBegan:withEvent:`は実装していない」ということなのでしょうか?

Comment: 極付近までは対象とはしないアプリを作成予定です。convertPointでタッチ座標を地図上の座標に変換しても、実装的には難しいものなのですね。ありがとうございます。  `ouchesBegan:withE‌​vent`は実装しておりますが、`co`に関する記述はしておりません。